# Karate - Variable to access request just like response

Tags: karate

Is there a variable like response for request in karate. I tried to look at the github issues and found the below example, but this does not seem to work for me.

```
* def temp = (karate.lastRequest)
* print '==============>' +(temp.body)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its [karate.prevRequest](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-prevRequest)

```
    * def temp = karate.prevRequest
    * def requestMethod = temp.method
    * def requestBody = temp.body
```

please find more example [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/request/request.feature)

Comment: I am not able to call this method from outside the feature. I have a service.feature where I construct the request and call the method. I call this feature from the test cases where I use the above steps. I get this error - 
                 javascript evaluation failed: temp.method, TypeError: Cannot get property "method" of null in <eval> at line number 1

However, when I call these steps in service.feature, it does work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can call `* def temp = karate.prevRequest` inside your `service.feature` and the `temp` variable should give those data from your testcases feature